# Where are the Intel HD Graphics Driver screen rotation settings stored?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have an HP laptop running Windows 10 with Intel HD Graphics 520. The latest version of the driver that I have (25.20.100.6472) no longer has the option for screen rotation. I assume there is a registry key which stores the rotation settings, because I only discovered this when I hooked up new monitors today and was unable to set them to portrait mode. My previous monitors worked fine in portrait mode, though I suspect I would have been unable to put them back into normal landscape mode with my current driver, had I tried to. My assumption is there must be a registry key (or some setting on the system) that I could manually tweak which would enable me to rotate one of my monitors. Note the built-in Windows 10 display setting for Orientation is grayed out. Previously I could only change this setting within the Intel HD Graphics control panel.

Comment: Are you using Tablet Mode? Is Auto-Rotation enabled?

Comment: @Romen no, I'm not using Tablet mode. In fact the option is disabled for me. I don't believe my laptop supports auto-rotation either.

Comment: That's a peculiar situation for you then. The Intel driver probably got rid of screen rotation settings because the Windows display settings are a standard place to configure that (if the drivers still support it). If that setting is disabled it's possibly because of the the driver not announcing support for that feature. Can you also confirm that the extra monitor is not in mirrored mode? I'm sure that orientation option only works when your desktop is extended. The laptop might even have a hard-coded orientation, so what happens if you use only an external display?

Comment: @Romen - I think you're on to something with the reason why the new driver doesn't have the option, and perhaps there's a bug in how it reports to the OS. But, I'm starting with the assumption that I know there's a bug, and I'm just trying to figure out an easy way to circumvent it. Note if I plug in the old monitors it works fine, because presumably it saved the settings for those specific monitors.